# CSS layout issue. Order divs vertically in columns of 4

Tags: css

I have a container with a set width and height. I have 20 elements inside. I'd like to arrange them vertically, in columns of 4 and preferably have the container scroll when the columns overflow on the x axis.

```
content 1    content 5    content 9     content 13    content 17   
content 2    content 6    content 10    content 14    content 18
content 3    content 7    content 11    content 15    content 19
content 4    content 8    content 12    content 16    content 20
```

Is there a method to achieve this using only CSS?

**EDIT**

Any solution would have to be supported in browsers as old as IE9

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/jw11oqo0/3/)

Comment: here's the answer: https://jsfiddle.net/awrtfv5e/

Comment: @Farside appreciate the reply, but the ordering of the elements is an issue. They need to be ordered as I've stated in my question.

Comment: then in your case you need to use Flex, find out https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `flex`

```css
.container {
  height:180px;
  background-color:#fff;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.container div{
  margin: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
  border: solid thin black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="">

  <div>
    content 1
  </div>
  <div>
    content 2
  </div>
  <div>
    content 3
  </div>
   <div>
    content 4
  </div>
   <div>
    content 5
  </div>
   <div>
    content 6
  </div>
   <div>
    content 7
  </div>
   <div>
    content 8
  </div>
   <div>
    content 9
  </div>
    <div>
    content 10
  </div>
   <div>
    content 11
  </div>
   <div>
    content 12
  </div>
   <div>
    content 13
  </div>
   <div>
    content 14
  </div>
   <div>
    content 15
  </div>
   <div>
    content 16
  </div>
   <div>
    content 17
  </div>
    <div>
    content 18
  </div>
   <div>
    content 19
  </div>
   <div>
    content 20
  </div>  

</div>
```

---

Update based on IE9 requirement (and also work for IE8), using `display: table` but you can use `display: inline-block;` or `float: left;` as well

```css
.container {
  background-color:#fff;
  display: table;                /* delete this for inline-block and float */
}
.container > div{
  display: table-cell;           /* table-cell   */
  /* display: inline-block;  */  /* or inline             */
  /* float: left;            */  /* or float              */
}
.container > div > div{
  margin: 5px;
  height: 30px;
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
  border: solid thin black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container" style="">

  <div>
    <div>
      content 1
    </div>
    <div>
      content 2
    </div>
    <div>
      content 3
    </div>
    <div>
      content 4
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>
      content 5
    </div>
    <div>
      content 6
    </div>
    <div>
      content 7
    </div>
    <div>
      content 8
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>
      content 9
    </div>
    <div>
      content 10
    </div>
    <div>
      content 11
    </div>
    <div>
      content 12
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>
      content 13
    </div>
    <div>
      content 14
    </div>
    <div>
      content 15
    </div>
    <div>
      content 16
    </div>
  </div>

  <div>
    <div>
      content 17
    </div>
    <div>
      content 18
    </div>
    <div>
      content 19
    </div>
    <div>
      content 20
    </div>  
  </div>  

</div>
```

Comment: just be cautious, when using this, @daft, check the browsers compatibility http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: Yeah the browser support is definitely an issue here, afraid I can't use this answer. Appreciate it though.

Comment: @Daft Are you aware of that the statistics on IE9 is less than 2% (actuallu closer to 1% than 2%)? ... and decreasing

Comment: @LGSon it's not up to me. If I had my way I'd develop chrome-only applications, but some of our clients are stuck in the past.

Comment: @Daft So do you want absolute position or can I change your markup?

Comment: Position absolute each element? We can't have that. Go ahead and change the mark up if you think that makes sense

Comment: @Daft Updated my answer with a 2:nd solution

Answer (score 0):

Check here:
[Dynamic layout](https://jsfiddle.net/Havock94/jw11oqo0/5/)

Basically you set a **min-width**

```
min-width: 200px;
```

So when a div goes under that size it will go on the next row. Also don't set a fixed width for the container otherwise it won't shrink when the window is resized.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the ordering of the elements is an issue. They need to be ordered as I've stated in my question

Comment: @Daft I don't know if you can arrange them top-to-bottom without changing the element order in the DOM

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your code is that you are mixing fixed size (5px of margin) with percentages (padding and width)

if you use only percentages and check the size you get it
[jsFiddle 2](https://jsfiddle.net/5uedu40g/)

maximum is 100%

```css
.container div{
  float: left;
  margin: 0px 0px 1% 1%x;
  width: 22%;
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
  padding:1%;
  border: solid thin black;
}
```

you have 4 columns so 
4*22%+
4*1%(margin)+
4*2*1%(padding is both right and left)
= 100%

in you example probably you exceeded the 100% then the 4th box goes down

otherwise if it's ok to use external components you could use something like bootstrap table 
http://getbootstrap.com/css/